Evaluation failed: a when sending media
I am trying to build a whatsapp bot using electron and whatsapp-web.js. The bot works fine with sending normal messsages like text, but when I try to pass an image it throws this error:
Server stdout: Error: Evaluation failed: a
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:229:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:107:16)
    at async Client.sendMessage (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:938:28)
    at async D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\server\script.js:167:17

my code:
var media = MessageMedia.fromFilePath(image_path);
console.log(media);
await client.sendMessage(groups[0]._serialized, media, {
    caption: message,
});

I debugged my code and there was nothing. the way I send images is by letting the user select an image and convert it to base64 in the html. when he clicks send, the base64 is re-converted back into an image in a local path like project/data/image.jpg and then that path is used in the MessageMedia.fromFilePath method. I ensured the image is saved and the path is correct. also the groups[0] returns the first common group between this number and the authenticated number and it works just fine. can someone help me?
EDIT:
I found that this way didn't pass the data parameter in the MessageMedia object, so I tried to create it manually like new MessageMedia('image/png', image //base64, fileName) and now it shows this error
Server stdout: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
    at window.WWebJS.mediaInfoToFile (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:520:35)
    at window.WWebJS.processMediaData (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:317:36)
    at window.WWebJS.sendMessage (pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:19:39)
    at pptr://__puppeteer_evaluation_script__:10:45
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:229:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:107:16)
    at async Client.sendMessage (D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:938:28)
    at async D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\server\script.js:167:17


Evaluation failed seems related to the evaluation of javascript .. are you sure that's related to the part of your code you showed? Anyway the error is thrown at at async D:\Projects\Web\Projects\Whatsapp Sender\server\script.js:167:17 .. 167...that's the line you included in the question?

that's the await client.sendMessage(groups[0]._serialized, media, { line @DiegoD

I actually found the problem I will get back to the code, reproduce more and post the solution

ok thanks for the clarification. Well talking about the more detailed error you shared, atop is the js function to decode a base64 string.. and it throws an error because the string is not valid. Maybe there's something wrong with the step creating the base64 string?

actually it's when loading the image after it has been created, like I said, I use the base64 to create a replica of the image but in a path I would know so that I can pass that path to the MessageMedia. The problem was that when creating MessageMedia, it didn't take any value in the data parameter, that's why

I believe it's because I am creating the image faster than the MessageMedia could read

and did you solve it then? or you still need to find a way to sync the operations? maybe the solution was calling the creation of the media file using await? I apologize if I'm just giving suggestions not needed anymore

I did find another way, I will post it

The solution is to use MessageMedia itself and not .fromFilePath(), I still don't know why does the data not contain anything when using .fromFilePath() but I tried using
var media = new MessageMedia(
    `image/${fileExtension}`,
    encoded_image, // => base64
    fileName
);

and it worked fine now. so the main reason is that I was trying to send an empty image
